# fedex address validation multiple results

Tags: javascript, xml, soap, fedex

So i have a function that is using the fedex api address validation and i'm trying to get back multiple results but no matter what address I type in regardless of ambiguity I only get 1 result. I've tried setting elements of the soap request to give me back more results but i guess i'm missing something.

bonus points for anyone able to tell me why the returned street address sometimes repeats.
I'll give it the address '1234 StreetName' and it returns '1234 StreetName1234 StreetName' in the response

```
/* Define SOAP parameters */

var fedexURL = 'https://gateway.fedex.com:443/web-services';
     var key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
     var password = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
     var accountNumber = XXXXXXX;
     var meterNumber = XXXXXXXXXX;

     var checkResidentialStatus = 1;
     var addressID = 'address1';

     // get address value from address fields
     var streetLines = nlapiGetFieldValue('custpage_custrecord_inv_address') + nlapiGetFieldValue('custpage_custrecord_inv_address');
     var city = nlapiGetFieldValue('custpage_custrecord_inv_city');
     var state = nlapiGetFieldValue('custpage_custrecord_inv_state_display');
     var postalCode = nlapiGetFieldValue('custpage_custrecord_inv_zip');
     var countryCode = nlapiGetFieldValue('custpage_custrecord_inv_country_display');


var soap = '<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v2">'+
'<SOAP-ENV:Body>'+
     '<AddressValidationRequest>'+
          '<WebAuthenticationDetail>'+
               '<UserCredential>'+
                    '<Key>'+key+'</Key>'+
                    '<Password>'+password+'</Password>'+
               '</UserCredential>'+
          '</WebAuthenticationDetail>'+
          '<ClientDetail>'+
               '<AccountNumber>'+accountNumber+'</AccountNumber>'+
               '<MeterNumber>'+meterNumber+'</MeterNumber>'+
          '</ClientDetail>'+
          '<TransactionDetail>'+
               '<CustomerTransactionId>WSVC_addressvalidation</CustomerTransactionId>'+
          '</TransactionDetail>'+
          '<Version>'+
               '<ServiceId>aval</ServiceId>'+
               '<Major>2</Major>'+
               '<Intermediate>0</Intermediate>'+
               '<Minor>0</Minor>'+
          '</Version>'+
          '<RequestTimestamp>2009-07-28T09:30:47-05:00</RequestTimestamp>'+
          '<Options>'+
                '<VerifyAddresses>1</VerifyAddresses>'+
               // '<CheckResidentialStatus>1</CheckResidentialStatus>'+
               '<MaximumNumberOfMatches>3</MaximumNumberOfMatches>'+
                '<StreetAccuracy>EXACT</StreetAccuracy>'+
               '<DirectionalAccuracy>EXACT</DirectionalAccuracy>'+
               '<CompanyNameAccuracy>EXACT</CompanyNameAccuracy>'+
               // '<ConvertToUpperCase>1</ConvertToUpperCase>'+
               '<RecognizeAlternateCityNames>1</RecognizeAlternateCityNames>'+
                '<ReturnParsedElements>1</ReturnParsedElements>'+
          '</Options>'+
          '<AddressesToValidate>'+
               '<AddressId>'+ addressID +'</AddressId>'+
               // '<CompanyName>String</CompanyName>'+
               '<Address>'+
                    '<StreetLines>'+streetLines+'</StreetLines>'+
                    '<City>'+city+'</City>'+
                    '<StateOrProvinceCode>'+state+'</StateOrProvinceCode>'+
                    '<PostalCode>'+postalCode+'</PostalCode>'+
                    '<CountryCode>'+countryCode+'</CountryCode>'+
                    '<Residential>1</Residential>'+
               '</Address>'+
          '</AddressesToValidate>'+
     '</AddressValidationRequest>'+
'</SOAP-ENV:Body>'+
'</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';

    var headers = [];
    headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/soap+xml';
    headers['User-Agent-x'] = 'SuiteScript-Call';

    // send request and parse response to json xml object
    var response = nlapiRequestURL(fedexURL, soap, headers);
    var xml = response.getBody();
    xml = jq.parseXML(xml);
```

Comment: Please post some examples of requests and their response

Comment: i have this same issue. I have tried adjusting the streetaccuracy and directionalaccuracy from medium to exact and loose and i still always get a single result for every address.

Answer (score 1):

The duplicate address is because:
 var streetLines = nlapiGetFieldValue('custpage_custrecord_inv_address') + nlapiGetFieldValue('custpage_custrecord_inv_address');

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issues, and I remembered getting multiple results back working with the API a few years ago, as well as scoring for each address and other details that didn't seem to be in the current API, examples, or documentation. I confirmed from a FedEx rep that "that was an older version" and **the current version of the Address Validation API (as of Sept 2015) apparently only returns one address**.

(Not sure about the repeating street name, though, I have not personally experienced that.)